# Do all bodies emit all type of radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, wavelength

Does only ideal black body radiate all type of wavelength at any temperature above 0K?

Edit:  My teacher told us that according to prevost theory all body radiates all type of wavelength? But I think it's just applicable for only perfect black body So that's where I am getting totally confused!

Comment: I wanted to say that By Khirchoffs law we know that emitters good are good absorbers and ideal black body is the best example which absorbs and emit all radiation hence it radiates all type of wavelength. But my teacher told me that all body radiates all types of wavelength so how is it possible for bodies other than ideally black body? I am totally confused!

Comment: It is simply that they do so but but with a different spectrum. See answer especially Tim Wescott's one.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you look a things.  If you take away the effects of absorbtion and reflection, any object at a temperature higher than 0K will emit radiation.

They won't do it on a black-body curve, necessarily -- materials have a property called "emissivity", which is the degree to which they emit radiation at a given wavelength.  At any given wavelength, the actual radiation emitted is equal to the black body radiation flux times the emissivity.

Some materials have very low emissivity, but nothing is perfect, so **any real material will emit a little bit of radiation at all wavelengths**.

Comment: But sir my teacher told us that according to prevost theory all body radiates all type of wavelength ? But I think it's just applicable for only perfect black body So that's where I am getting totally confused!

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Your confusion lies in believing that only perfect black body emitters emit at all wavelengths -- that's not so, and you can do a web search on "emissivity" if you cannot believe me.  But if you just cannot believe your teacher, and you can't believe anyone else who tells you this, why are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

As Wikipedia states:

> A black body or blackbody is an idealized physical body that absorbs all incident electromagnetic radiation, regardless of frequency or angle of incidence.

A common example of a real body which doesn't absorb all of the incident radiation, i.e., discriminates on the basis of frequency, is a **leaf**. Here a part of the incoming radiation is reflected and a part is transmitted without absorption.

Where as [Prevost's theory](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Prevost-theory-of-heat-exchange---Laws-of-Heat-Transfer_36233/) says:

> Every object emits heat radiations at all finite temperatures (except 0 K) as well as it absorbs radiations from the surroundings.

Which doesn't concern with the frequency of the emitted/absorbed radiation and simply states that a body emits radiation at any given temperature above absolute zero, such as we Emmit infrared radiation.

Answer (score 1):

One has to keep clear what are models,and what are measurements. Models are mathematical [formulae dependent](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) on assumptions and the perfect blackbody curve for each temperature can be calculated and is unique at each temperature. How much the real measurements fit the theoretical curves has to be tested by measurement.

See this curve for radiation at the top of the atmosphere, coming from the earth , out to space, which is a candidate black body:

[image: topatms]

> Outgoing spectral radiance at the top of Earth's atmosphere showing the absorption at specific frequencies and the principle absorber. For comparison, the red curve shows the flux from a classic "blackbody" at 294°K (≈21°C ≈ 69.5°F).

So it is absorption and emission differences that will give a different shaped data curve than the one  predicted for the given black body at that temperature.

This is true for all bodies, but the blackbody shape  is only approximately followed. Theoretically all frequencies are emitted and absorbed , but the curves limit the probability for the too small frequencies and the too large ones to appear in a measurement.

The best fit for the black body curve measured in nature is with the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Features).